# System Time Synchronization Procedure

Tags: clock-synchronization

I am looking for procedure which I can execute in cron to synch the system time in clustered servers. Can any of the experienced SME's please help?

Comment: What's wrong with NTP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [periodically overridding NTP for simulation purposes](http://serverfault.com/questions/219526/periodically-overridding-ntp-for-simulation-purposes)

Answer (score 7):

[NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) is the answer.
NTP is ***always*** the answer to "How do I synchronize the clocks on some machines?"

A full tutorial on setting up NTP is far beyond the scope of this site, however you will find tutorials all over the internet.  The gist of it is:

1. Install the NTP software if your OS doesn't already come with it.
   (If you're really in a bind and need to build it yourself source is available at [ntp.org](http://www.ntp.org))
2. Run the NTP daemon on one of your machines as a "server"
   (point this machine at some servers from [pool.ntp.org](http://www.pool.ntp.org/) to get its time)
3. Run the NTP daemon on the rest of your machines, pointing them to your local NTP server configured in (2).

This will produce a far better synchronization than any cron job could manage.